# .mid truncated when playing in android

Tags: android, media-player, midi

I have midi file, in which music begins, let's say, from 1:30. It's play ok with Windows player, but when I try to play it with android mediaPlayer it just truncate it, and  begin play it immediately. No matter, I play with native Player, or play it from my own application. I thought that this is known problem, but I found nothing about this.